# Extract values from raster ArcGIS 10.x

Tags: arcgis, raster

I just got a vegetation raster. Its pixels have several fields (i.e. basal area oaks, density of oaks, volume of oaks, pixel value, etc). How do I extract only selected field values to a set of XY points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary tool that you'll be working with is [Raster to Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_Point/001200000007000000/) (Conversion toolbox). It includes a parameter to pick which field to pull data from:

> The Field parameter allows you to choose which attribute field of the input raster dataset will become an attribute in the output feature class. If a field is not specified, the cell values of the input raster (the VALUE field) will become a column with the heading Grid_code in the attribute table of the output feature class.

If you want to exclude certain values or subset the data, that can be done either before converting (using [Con](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) or similar) or after (select by attribute and export or delete). Doing it afterwards gives you a bit more flexibility, but leads to larger point datasets.